# How to embed python console like pythonanywhere in django website?

Tags: python, django, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a python online console like pythonanywhere in my Django website. Is there any Django-package for it.
 I have tried all the other 3rd party online consoles but I don't want to use that.

I want to create my own console in Django website

what i have try

```
from IPython import embed
def embed(request):
   return Httpresponse(embed())
```

Comment: this does not have much to do with django. Just do a subprocess.call with the command user entered and return the output of the call as httpresponse

Comment: no i want to create online python console where user can do python coding same like pythonanywhere

Comment: example  https://www.pythonanywhere.com/embedded/

Comment: that's too broad. You are asking how do i build a complete system. Show us what you have tried break into specific problems then re-ask the question

Comment: just tell how to and where to start i will manage further any package can help me"?

Comment: can any package help me? are you kidding? there are teams building sites like python anywhere for years and you think there is some easy tutorial on how to build that? its like asking I want to program photoshop which tools do you recommend.

Comment: so any other option !!!